# How to export a svg to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, svg

I have a Python application which at some point generates a native svg image. This svg is then immediately sent through a web server (and is catch in a xlink:href attribute).

I would like to make a copy of it and to be able to see it after the server have been closed. As it is just for testing I don't care about the format the picture is saved, I only want it to be "human visualisable". How can I do that?

I work on a ubuntu OS, use Python 3, and the image is generated by Datashader (it that is relevant).

---

If that wasn't clear: I don't want to generates the svg. My svg is already generated and I only want to save it in a file.

Comment: A `.svg` file is perfectly human visualisable, just open it in any browser. Do you mean you want a SVG vector image rendered to a PNG raster image perhaps?

Comment: I don't care. I can't open it simply while it is just a Python object, so even if it is svg, png or whatever as long as it is saved I will be happy.

Comment: So... `open('out.svg', 'w').write(svg_string)`? SVG is just XML. I'm a bit baffled that you are sending the SVG content to a web server but have difficulty writing it to disk. Am I missing something?

Comment: "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Image". How do you convert it to a string ? Does it stay readable after that ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what OS you're using, etc., but this may be a start in the right direction:

Assuming you have already allocated a particular file, since it has been created and sent through server (as you stated), then you could just use something like:

```
import pysvg.structures
import pysvg.builders
import pysvg.text
import subprocess

mySvg = pysvg.strcture.svg()
savePathAndFile = "/myPath/testSvg.svg"
mySvg.save(savePathAndFile)

subprocess.call(['/myPath/toSVG/viewingApp', savePathAndFile])
```

where /myPath/toSVG/viewingApp is a terminal command for running an svg processing application, such as inkscape.

Comment: <<AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'save'>> (I assumed my svg image Python object is equivalent to you mySvg but maybe that's not the case)

Comment: In my example the object is a pysvg structure, as opposed to a native 'image'.  Since there was no code in the question, I'm not sure exactly what you're framework looks like, but this example is a basic implementation for saving an .svg file via python packages.  

Check this brief article for more details...

 http://florian-berger.de/en/articles/creating-simple-svg-from-python/

Comment: Well, mine is a native image, and the save of it is the whole point of my question. Your link is about how to create a svg, in my case I already have a svg and I just want to save it.

Comment: @Martin Valgur comment captures my thoughts as well.  If you are sending it over a server, then I don't see what is keeping you from writing to a file, but again, if you could add some code to your question, it would go a long way in clarifying. Sorry the link I posted didn't help you; I was hoping it would give context for the pysvg structure methods.  Thanks

Comment: The code won't help, it is basically "img = function(parameters)" where function generates a svg image (actually it's the shade function from datashader.transfer_function)